# Cassandra Update/Upsert does not set Static Column?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

I am trying to "Upsert" data into my table with CQLSSTableWriter. Everything works fine, except for my static column not being set correctly. They end up being null for every occasion. My static column is defined as `brand TEXT static`.

After failing with the CQLSSTableWriter, I went into the cqlsh and tried to update the static column manually:

```
update keyspace.data set brand='Nestle' where id = 'whatever' and date = '2015-10-07';
```

and with a batch as well (even though it should not matter)

```
begin batch 
update keyspace.data set brand='Nestle' where id = 'whatever' and date = '2015-10-07'; 
apply batch;
```

My "brand" column still shows null when I retrieve some of my data (`select * from keyspace.data LIMIT 100;`)

My entire schema:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.data (
    id text,
    date text,
    ts timestamp,
    id_two text,
    brand text static,
    latitude double,
    longitude double,
    signals_double map<text, double>,
    signals_string map<text, text>,
    name text static,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id, date), ts, id_two)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts ASC, id_two ASC);
```

The reason why I chose Update instead of Insert is because I have collections that I do not want to overwrite, but rather add more elements to. Using insert would overwrite the previously stored elements of my collections.

Why can I not set a static column with an Update query?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your table schema?

Comment: @Aaron done. The problem might be related to the CQLSSTableWriter not setting the static columns at all on insert. In fact, I thought that when I add the static columns on my first row, all other rows will "automatically" reference to the static columns of that first row. When I do not set the columns "brand" and "name" in my row that I pass to the CQLSSTableWriter, I am not able to update the static values afterwards. Interesting is that NO row will contain my two static values, even though I expect there to be at least one row (the first) to contain the values.

Comment: I am logging all rows that I pass to the writer and can definitely say that I am passing the columns "brand" and "name" for the first row. They are discarded for some reason. Or is the CQLSSTableWriter filling columns that are not set in the row's Map<String,Object> with null? This would maybe explain why the values of the first row disappear. But it does not explain why I can not re-set the static values in cqlsh afterwards?